# Video editing + audio mixing + sound design at all useful as a UX designer?

Tags: ux-field

I'm pivoting away from digital content design/production (some video, mostly audio) to UX design, and wondering what the vibe is regarding production skills in UX? I typically see more graphic design types drift toward the field and haven't found any relevant articles online about this.

Comment: If you are interested in finding out about UX career paths and skills required, it is better to use other forums like Quora or reddit where there are more information about how to transition into this field and talk to other people who are going through the same journey. UXSE is mostly focused on specific UX issues, so this is out of scope for the forum.

Answer (score 2):

UX is not about design or interfaces. It is about researching users, finding the right problems, dissecting them and translating them into solutions which are later tested and retested.

Graphic designers drift towards the field because originally they were the only ones in a company designing graphics, so management types decided interfaces were fit for them too because interface = visuals. This was exacerbated by market demand. However, this trend and logic is not true anymore. Other professions, such as psychologists, ethnographers, architects, etc find complementary skills for UX and make the switch.

You could focus solely on UI design but still need to understand the principles of interfaces and the research behind them, as well as the bigger picture of the product, impact on development, on the user and not making siloed decisions purely based on aesthetics.

As for you, there are certain pockets in the industry focused more on production, such as: [UI Design in Films](https://www.core77.com/posts/28183/fantastical-ui-design-from-sci-fi-movies-28183), [Installations](https://gmunk.com/DoorDash-Mosaic), [Gaming](https://www.hudsandguis.com/), etc.

More [about UX vs UI](https://uxdesign.cc/what-is-ux-what-is-ui-in-2020-ddb48aaa7853).

Answer (score 2):

UX Design is about understanding user goals and motivations. After understanding them, a UX designer designs an appropriate solution that meets the user, customer, and business goals.

To answer your specific question, there are ways that can leverage the skills you mention:

### Video Editing

Communication is a key aspect of UX design: communicate to clients, communicate design plan to stakeholders, communicating to a development team, and more.

Video is a communication format that can be leveraged for UX purposes. For example, you can use video to communicate user pain points (I picture the cheesy infomercials with the struggle with a "before" product). Video can also communicate a potential design solution to stakeholder and/or users.

### Audio Mixing & Sound Design

This can be used as a communication tool as well. At times, soundbites or small recordings from user interviews provide key insights into pain points and goals. Audio mixing a "best of" compilation of user feedback will help communicate user research to others on your team.

A trending specialization in UI is Voice UI. Skills in audio mixing and sound design can be leveraged to offer better design solutions in this particular domain.

Answer (score 2):

I would say these are skills to achieve certain goals, just the way visual design an UI design would be. UX is a mindset of putting the user 1st in order to improve their experience of using a product or service. Of course research is a critical part of UX.

I believe your skills will be critical in the domains of AR & VR UX which are new and different platforms going beyond the flat screen. Immersion and Presence are key factor designing a great UX in these platform.